# Ffmpeg concatenate video file with hw acceleration using cuvid

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to use Nvidia hardware acceleration for FFmpeg using cuvid. I want to merge multiple h264 / mp4 files using a complex filter (simplified example):

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.ts -y -fflags +genpts -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4
```

I use the following version FFmpeg and Ubuntu 16.04:

```
version 3.4.2-1~16.04.york0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 20160609
```

If i run the command i get the following error:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_concat_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
```

When i remove the hwaccel flag the command runs but i get a massive CPU load. How can i use a concat complex_filter in combination with cuvid hw acceleration?

SOLUTION

The concat demuxing worked. The output of the encoder is now in h264. I group the files in a `list.txt`:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Then run ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy result.mp4
```

Comment: The immediate solution is to convertthe pixel format beforehand `[0:v:0]format=yuv420p[v];[v][0:a]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1`. But what's the need for concat in this case?

Comment: I simplified the example with one file just to make the command as simple as possible. If i define the format i get the same error:

fmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.ts -y -fflags +genpts -filter_complex "[0:v:0]format=yuv420p[v];[v][0:a:0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mp4

Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented

Comment: @Gyan I want to concatenate multiple files into one mp4 using cuvid hw acceleration. For now this only works if I remove the hwaccel flag but then it does not use the GPU and i get a massive CPU spike.

Comment: The concat filter will not use the GPU in any case. You can speed up the op by using a hardware encoder. And drop the hw decoding.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable feedback. I will try to output the video as h264 by our tuners (recording live TV) and use the ffmpeg concat demuxer instead of the filter_complex solution.

Comment: The concat demuxing worked. The output of the encoder is now in h264. I group the files in a list.txt:

file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'


ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy result.mp4)

Comment: You can answer your own questions on this site. Since you found a solution you can add it as an answer instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

The concat demuxing worked. The output of the encoder is now in h264. I group the files in a list.txt:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy result.mp4
```